# The best way to create a new table in Sqlite using Ruby on Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake

So what's the best way to create new tables in a Sqlite database in Rails 2. I have created the database using rake db:migrate command. So should I write individual sql scripts to create a database or use rake somehow. I don't need scaffolding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically use migrations.

Some useful help on how to use migrations is available at http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/understandingmigrations and http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/UsingMigrations. A good cheatsheet that I use is also available at http://dizzy.co.uk/ruby_on_rails/cheatsheets/rails-migrations.

Basically migrations use ruby code to create your database tables for you. It is far easier (in my opinion at least) to use nice ruby code to do this rather than SQL DDL - it also does various things automatically for you (like adding `id` fields to all your tables as rails requires). You can then use rake tasks to actually apply the migrations to your database. The other major advantage that migrations give you is that they are reverseable - so your database is versioned and you can easily jump from one version to another.

Comment: Another source is the Rails guide at http://guides.rails.info/migrations/migrations.html

Comment: All the links except for the (cheatsheet) are dead.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid writing CREATE/ALTER table scripts and use ActiveRecord migrations instead. A few reasons spring to mind:

- Portability: it's much easier to let
  AR deal with cross-platform flavour
  differences
- Change control: your
  migrations can manage changes in
  both directions with the VERSION=
  option, something that's not easy to
  do with SQL
- It's the Rails way:
  follow the Rails conventions unless
  you have a compelling reason not to
  do so
- Simplicity: you don't have to worry about id and timestamp columns when you use migrations, which saves you having to remember them if you work in SQL

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using scaffolding then you should use `script/generate migration` to create a migration file for each table. There is no need to use sql scripts. After creating some migrations you can apply them to your database using rake db:migrate.